# Holding signal true for x seconds in LabView

Tags: control, matlab, data-acquisition, labview

I'm trying to create an automatic startup override system whereby when an ESD override button is clicked, a signal will be held true for 10 seconds overriding my ESD interlocks.

[image]

This seems like there really ought to be a simple solution:

1. Restart Activated.
2. Set timer to 0 and start.
3. While Timer < x seconds output true.
4. Then revert to false and stop timer.

However, I have no idea of how to implement this in LabVIEW so would appreciate some help!

---

I've tried implementing this using a case with a wait command in it but I'm getting a "member of a cycle" error.

[image]

Comment: This should be migrated to LabVIEW.SE. A quick answer is to trigger a delay timer in the case structure which when timed out writes '1' back to your dashed line as a named variable. For it to run again this variable must be cleared. This is very basic LabVIEW stuff.

Comment: Your second drawing will cause an error as you are creating a loop. You need to create a variable inside the first case, and set it TRUE when times out. A copy of the variable is what stops the function. You have much to learn...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a pure programming question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't show more of your schematic, I guess you have some kind of process which runs again and again within a loop.

One way to accomplish your task is using a shift register to carry data into the next iteration of the loop. If the button is pressed, `(current time + 10 seconds)` is written to the register, otherwise, it stays unchanged:

[image]

You should always initialize a shift register (wire something to the left input) unless you have a reason not to do so, because shift register will keep the value from the last time the VI ran.